# How to apply a function in Pandas to a cell in every row where a different cell in that same row meets a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, conditional-statements

I am trying to use the pandas string method `"str.zfill"` to add leading zeros to a cell in the same column for every row in the dataframe where another cell in that row meets a certain condition. So for any given row in my DataFrame "excodes", when the value in column "LOB_SVC_CD" is "MTG", apply the `str.zfill(5)` method to the cell in column "PS_CD". When the value in "LOB_SVC_CD" is not "MTG" leave the value in "PS_CD" as is.

I've tried a few custom functions, "np.where" and a few apply/map lambdas. I'm getting errors on all of them.

```
#Custom Function
def add_zero(column):
    if excodes.loc[excodes.LOB_SVC_CD == 'MTG']:
        excodes.PS_CD.str.zfill(5)
    else:
        return excodes.PS_CD

excodes['code'] = excodes.apply(add_zero)

#Custom Function with For Loop
def add_zero2(column):
    code = []
    for row(i) in column:
        if excodes.LOB_SVC_CD == 'MTG':
        code.append(excodes.PS_CD.str.zfill(5))
    else:
        code.append(excodes.PS_CD)
excodes['Code'] = code

excodes['code'] = excodes.apply(add_zero)

#np.Where
mask = excodes[excodes.LOB_SVC_CD == 'MTG']
excodes['code'] = pd.DataFrame[np.where(mask, excodes.PS_CD.str.zfill(5), excodes.PS_CD)]

#Lambda
excodes['code'] = excodes['LOB_SVC_CD'].map(lambda x: excodes.PS_CD.str.zfill(5)) if x[excodes.LOB_SVC_CD == 'MTG'] else excodes.PS_CD)  

#Assign with a "Where"
excodes.assign((excodes.PS_CD.str.zfill(5)).where(excodes.LOB_SVC_CD == 'MTG'))
```

Expected results will be either:

- create a new called "code" with all values in "PS_CD" are given leading zeroes in rows where `excodes.LOB_SVC_CD == 'MTG'`
- adding leading zeroes to the values in `excodes["PS_CD"]` when the row `excodes['LOB_SVC_CD'] == 'MTG'`

Error Messages I'm getting are - on each of the approaches I've tried:

```
#Custom Function: 
"ValueError: ('The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index PS_CD')"

# Custom Function with For Loop:
"SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"

#np.Where:
"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (152,7) (720,) (720,)"

#Apply Lambda:
"string indices must be integers"

#Assign with a "Where":
"TypeError: assign() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work :)

```
# Ensure the data in the PS_CD are strings
data["PS_CD"] = data["PS_CD"].astype(str)

# Iterate over all rows
for index in data.index:
  # If the LOB_SVC_CD is "MTG"
  if (data.loc[index, "LOB_SVC_CD"] == "MTG"):
    # Apply the zfill(5) in the PS_CD on the same row (index)
    data.loc[index, "PS_CD"] = data.loc[index, "PS_CD"].zfill(5)

# Print the result
print(data)
```

Alternative way (maybe a bit more Python-ish) :)

```
# Ensure the data in the PS_CD are strings
data["PS_CD"] = data["PS_CD"].astype(str)

# Custom function for applying the zfill
def my_zfill(x, y):
  return y.zfill(5) if x == "MTG" else y

# Iterate over the data applying the custom function on each row
data["PS_CD"] = pd.Series([my_zfill(x, y) for x, y in zip(data["LOB_SVC_CD"], data["PS_CD"])])
```

Comment: Thanks Mikulas! Both approaches worked. I'm relatively new to python so perhaps you can help me understand why you used or needed to use "index" in the first approach. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(data = [['123', 'MTG'],['321', 'CLOC']], columns = ['PS_CD', 'LOB_SVC_CD'])
>>> df
  PS_CD LOB_SVC_CD
0   123        MTG
1   321       CLOC
>>>
>>> df['PS_CD'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['PS_CD'].zfill(5) if row['LOB_SVC_CD'] == 'MTG' else row['PS_CD'], axis='columns')
>>> df
   PS_CD LOB_SVC_CD
0  00123        MTG
1    321       CLOC
```

Using lambda will return value for every row, zfilled PS_CD if LOB_SVC_CD was MTG else original PS_CD.